# How can I fix 'Something went wrong initializing the native ReactNativeLocalization module' error when deploying a React Native iOS build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, iosdeployment

So I want to create a build for iOS on my mac and I successfully did that. But currently my having these below errors:

`[Sat May 27 2023 13:03:34.703]  ERROR    Something went wrong initializing the native ReactNativeLocalization module.
Please check your configuration.
Did you run 'react-native link'?

[Sat May 27 2023 13:03:34.704]  ERROR    TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'localization.language')
[Sat May 27 2023 13:03:34.705]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

[Sat May 27 2023 13:03:35.915]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)`

I tried pod install and update also but it's still not working. All I can see is white blank screen on my emulator.